# Use coefficient of variation as weight in GAM

Tags: generalized-linear-model, generalized-additive-model

Is it possible or reasonable to use the coefficient of variation in a GAM / GLM as a weight to incorporate uncertainty into a response variable?

I've got density estimates that have a CV value and need to model while taking into account the observation error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly then yes you can. Though whether you can in practice and how you do this will depend on the software implementation you wish to use. For example:

In R's `glm()` and `mgcv::gam()` there is a `weights` argument. `?glm` says

> Non-`NULL` `weights` can be used to indicate that different
>   observations have different dispersions (with the values in
>   `weights` being inversely proportional to the dispersions); or
>   equivalently, when the elements of `weights` are positive integers
>   `w_i`, that each response `y_i` is the mean of `w_i` unit-weight
>   observations.

From that description, I think you would need to use `weights = 1/CV` to get the desired effect.

Comment: Thanks - yes, this is what I ended up interpreting as well.  However, I had to normalize the weights (weights = weights/mean(weights) ) to get it to work. Not 100% sure why, but otherwise it just didn't work properly.

Comment: I've seen that happen too in one case, but not with others data sets. I think what might be happening is the likelihood is being swamped by the weights and that's leading the model to be erroneously estimated with very low error &mdash; in the one example where it didn't work well confidence bands on smooth went to almost zero.